# How to Access Current File Path in Python C Extension

Tags: python, c, attributes, python-c-api

In Python, you can get the current file path with the `__file__` attribute.

```
print(__file__)
```

How can I access this attribute from a Python C Extension? I tried the following code, but the attribute doesn’t exist.

```
if (PyObject_HasAttrString(module, "__file__")) {
    PyObject *string = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "__file__");
    const char *path = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(string);
}
```

Comment: what is `module`?

Comment: I define the `module` variable in the c extension with the `PyModule_Create` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on when you want to access the `__file__` attribute and exactly how you create the module.

In single-phase initialization (when you call `PyModule_Create` within `PyInit_yourmodulename`) `__file__` is set *after* the `PyInit_*` function is called. Therefore you can only access it after that point, when the module is fully imported.

In [multi-phase initialization](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#multi-phase-initialization), where `PyInit_yourmodulename` returns a `PyModuleDef` object and then the `Py_mod_create` slot of that `PyModuleDef` is called, you can set the filename from the `spec` passed to `Py_mod_create`. The [`ModuleSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec) object has an attribute `origin`. This corresponds to the file that the module was loaded from. Thus you can set the `__file__` attribute of your module from `spec.origin`.

If you're creating your modules outside of the `PyInit_yourmodulename` system (for example, creating multiple modules from a single file) then you're out of luck and will have to work out what `__file__` is yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. It looks like I’ll have to migrate to multi-phase initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidW, I can now access the `__file__` attribute.

```
static int module_exec(PyObject *self) {
    PyObject *string = PyObject_GetAttrString(self, "__file__");
    const char *path = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(string);

    printf("Current path: %s\n", path);
    return 0;
}

static PyModuleDef_Slot ModuleSlots[] = {
    {Py_mod_exec, module_exec},
    {0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef Module = {
    .m_base = PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "__init__",
    .m_size = 0,
    .m_slots = ModuleSlots
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_Module(void) {
    printf("Initialising...");
    return PyModuleDef_Init(&Module);
}
```

I could have added the `Py_mod_create` slot, but I do not need it for my project.